# Online MySQL database gives "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied"

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, database-connection, access-denied

I am creating a Swing application in Eclipse, which I need to have access to an **online** MySQL database. So I followed [this link](https://databases-auth.000webhost.com/) which allows me to build my database in PhpMyAdmin.

I made my database and now I am trying to connect to it through my application, but I get this error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'id148583_test_database'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>       at main.ReadProperties.(ReadProperties.java:40)
>       at main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:17)

Here is my code :

***MainClass.java***

```
package main;

import java.sql.Connection;
import gui.GuiFrame;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class MainClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ReadProperties prop = new ReadProperties("connectionprops.properties");     
        Connection conn = prop.getConnection();  
    }

}
```

***ReadProperties.java***

```
package main;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ReadProperties {

    private String db_user;
    private String db_password;
    private String db_driver;
    private String db_connection;

    private Connection connection;

    public ReadProperties(String filename){
        Properties propfile = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(filename);
            propfile.load(input);

            db_user = propfile.getProperty("db_user");
            db_password = propfile.getProperty("db_password");
            db_driver = propfile.getProperty("db_driver");
            db_connection = propfile.getProperty("db_connection");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection( db_connection, db_user, db_password);
        } catch (IOException | SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

and my ***properties file*** :

```
db_user=id148583_test_database
db_password=test_pass
db_driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db_connection=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/id148583_test_database
```

I set on my own the username and the password. I also have **MySqlConnector jar** added. What is wrong? Can't I connect to an online database this way?

Comment: The error message contains all the details you need. Access is denied for that particular user with the given password.

Comment: @f1sh Yes but does the problem exist because my database is online? I am sure about the correctness of my username and password.

Comment: "Access denied for user 'id148583_test_database'@'localhost'" - Notice that MySQL considers the *host* as part of the user credentials. So make sure you grant access to that user *on that host* (or wildcard `%`). See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html

Comment: @JimmyB could you please explain how I can do this?

Comment: Use PhpMyadmin or whatever management tool you have to configure access for a certain user and the corresponding host.